# How to make a function call in ios to wait, till the block inside that function is executed completely?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, objective-c-blocks

Inside the following function, I've used a block. But when I call this function, it is returned even before the block is executed. I understood that Block inturn uses the threads and executes separately so that the function doesnt wait for it to return. But, Is there any other way I could make the function execution wait, or any other way to achieve the functionality of this block without using the block itself ?

```
-(int)findCurrentZip
{
        CLLocation *userLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[self findCurrentLatitude]
                                                              longitude:[self findCurrentLongitude]];
         int zipcode;
        self.myGeocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        [self.myGeocoder 
         reverseGeocodeLocation:userLocation
         completionHandler: (id)^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
             if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0)
             {
                 NSLog(@"Placemarks: %@",placemarks);
                 CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0]; 
                 NSLog(@"Country = %@", placemark.country);
                 NSLog(@"Postal Code = %@", placemark.postalCode);
                 zipcode = (int)placemark.postalCode;
                 NSLog(@"Locality = %@", placemark.locality);
                 NSLog(@"Country%@",[placemarks lastObject]);
             }
             else if (error == nil && [placemarks count] == 0)
             {
                 NSLog(@"No results were returned.");
             }
             else if (error != nil)
             {

             }
        }];

        return zipcode;
    }
```

Comment: just as a note. there is a reason that postalCode is a NSString in CLPlacemark. Zip codes can start with a 0!

Comment: oh, and `(int)placemark.postalCode` does not convert that NSString to an int ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I would suggest to rethink your design. Instead of returning the zipCode value from this method, call into some other method in the completionHandler (create a protocol / delegate or whatever). The `reverseGeocodeLocation::` method can take some time, and you don't want to pause execution of the main thread waiting on the result.

If you do want to block though, you might consider using (abusing?) a `dispatch_semaphore_t`. Initialize it to 0 and `dispatch_semaphore_wait` after the call to `reverseGeocodeLocation::`. In the completionHandler signal it with `dispatch_semaphore_signal`.

More information: [Using Dispatch Semaphores to Regulate the Use of Finite Resources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW24)

edit: and like others suggested, declare zipCode with a __block qualifier

Comment: Also don't use 'waiting' pattern, because when you do call `findCurrentZip` from the main thread accidentally, your app get stuck until you'll find ZIP code. Bad design ...

Comment: Yeah, Seems Protocol / Delegate is the optimized and right technique for this scenario..