# Reverse Geocoding class method

Tags: ios, geocoding, grand-central-dispatch

The following class method obviously returns null value due to the fact that executes asynchronously the `geocodeAddressString` block.

What is the best practice that could make this work through GCD?

```
+ (CLLocationCoordinate2D)reverseGeocoding:(NSString *)address
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  __block streetAddressCoordinates;

    CLGeocoder *streetAddressGeocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [streetAddressGeocoder
        geocodeAddressString:address

        completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
        {
            if ([placemarks count] > 0 && error == nil)
            {
                CLPlacemark  *firstPlacemark;
                firstPlacemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                streetAddressCoordinates = firstPlacemark.location.coordinate;
            }
            else if ([placemarks count] == 0 && error == nil){
                NSLog(@"Found no placemarks.");
            }
            else if (error != nil){ NSLog(@"An error occurred = %@", error);
            }
     }];

     return streetAddressCoordinates;
}
```

Comment: I could cmd-c / cmd-v my answer, but I'll give a link instead: [How to make a function call in ios to wait, till the block inside that function is executed completely?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243871/how-to-make-a-function-call-in-ios-to-wait-till-the-block-inside-that-function/12244293#12244293)

Comment: I tried                             streetAddressCoordinates.latitude=0;
while (streetAddressCoordinates.latitude==0)  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];          and worked but I dont think that is the best solution.

Comment: lol, polling is really bad, please avoid it. I would really suggest you redesign your code, and add a callback block argument to the method, or perhaps notify the observers via `NSNotificationCenter`. I know that's not what you are asking, that's why I am not posting an answer.

Comment: Solved by passing block as parameter to the method  -(void)geocode:(NSString *)address result:(void (^) (CLLocationCoordinate2D responce))handler {...)